# Неправильно переводит с класса "character" в "numeric"

Tags: r

Всем привет :)

Столкнулась с проблемой. 
Мне нужно, чтобы последняя колонка (dat[, 11]) отображалась как число, впоследствии по ней нужно будет отсортировать от меньшего к большему.

Этот код работает и переводит в числовой формат, но числа там совершенно не совпадают с изначальными данными.

Вы не знаете, в чем может быть проблема?

```
 dat <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", na.strings="Not Available", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  ha <- c("heart attack")

  heart_attack_all <- if(outcome == ha) {
   ha_a <- as.data.frame(cbind(dat[, 2], ## hospital
                            dat[, 7], ## state
                            dat[, 11])) ## heart attack
    colnames(ha_a) <- c("hospital name", "state", "outcome")
    ha_a[, 3] <- as.numeric(ha_a[, 3])
    return(ha_a) 
  }
```

Если нужен файл, чтобы прогнать код, его можно скачать [по этой ссылке.](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2FProgAssignment3-data.zip)

Comment: После импорта данных через `read.csv` `is.numeric(dat[, 11])` `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

При попытки выполнить код - ошибка "Error: object 'outcome' not found" (на самом деле не ясно где присваивается значение).

Анализируем Ваш код по шагам:

```
# открыли файл и присвоили значение ha
dat <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", na.strings="Not Available", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ha <- c("heart attack")

#появляется переменная outcome без значения
heart_attack_all <- if(outcome == ha) {
#создали data frame из 2, 7, 11 столбцов dat
     ha_a <- as.data.frame(cbind(dat[, 2], ## hospital
                                 dat[, 7], ## state
                                 dat[, 11])) ## heart attack
#присвоили новые значения именам столбцов
     colnames(ha_a) <- c("hospital name", "state", "outcome")
#и явно указали, что столбец outcome есть число
     ha_a[, 3] <- as.numeric(ha_a[, 3])
     return(ha_a) 
 }
```

На самом деле если выполнить код:

```
ha_a <- as.data.frame(cbind(dat[, 2], ## hospital
                            dat[, 7], ## state
                            dat[, 11])) ## heart attack
colnames(ha_a) <- c("hospital name", "state", "outcome")
ha_a[, 3] <- as.numeric(ha_a[, 3])
```

то значения ha_a[, 3] уже  не соответствуют значениям dat[, 11]

Например для **NYU HOSPITALS CENTER**

```
ha_a[, 3] = 1
dat[, 11] = 10.1
```

причина в

```
ha_a[, 3] <- as.numeric(ha_a[, 3])
```

Как комментировал Artem Klevtsov:

> После импорта данных через read.csv is.numeric(dat[, 11]) TRUE.

и остается таковым до выполнения

> ha_a[, 3] <- as.numeric(ha_a[, 3])

лишнее преобразование.

Как понимаю задача: **выбрать три столбца (2, 7, 11) и потом отсортировать по 11 столбцу** (наличие условия if(outcome == ha)  не совсем ясно).

Решение на основании пакета **dplyr**

```
# отбираем столбцы, наименования столбцов остаются как после прочтения файла
dat.dplr <- select(dat, 2, 7, 11)
# сортируем
dat2.dplr <- arrange_at(dat.dplr, 3)

#при необходимости изменить наименования испольюзуйте
colnames(dat2.dplr) <- c("hospital name", "state", "outcome")
```

В случае использования только основного синтаксиса

```
# отбираем столбцы, наименования столбцов остаются как после прочтения файла
dat.bs <- dat[, c(2, 7, 11)]
# сортируем
dat2.bs <- dat.bs[ order(dat.bs[,3]), ]

#при необходимости изменить наименования используйте
colnames(dat2.bs) <- c("hospitalname", "state", "outcome")
```